# Rename dictionary keys according to another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x

(In Python 3)

I have dictionary `old`. I need to change some of its keys; the keys that need to be changed and the corresponding new keys are stored in a dictionary `change`. What's a good way to do it? Note that there may be an overlap between `old.keys()` and `change.values()`, which requires that I'm careful applying the change.

The following code would (I think) work but I was hoping for something more concise and yet Pythonic:

```
new = {}
for k, v in old.items():
  if k in change:
    k = change[k]
  new[k] = v
old = new
```

Comment: I added the python tag since this isn't entirely Python3 specific. My answer also works in Python2.7

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
old = {change.get(k,k):v for k,v in old.items()}
```